Why isn't my 2D array in my class object updating?
So I've been working on a small text based adventure in python and a couple snippets of code have been giving me a large amount of trouble, namely a part that ensures that any visited rooms would be set to "empty" instead of "treasure" or "monster".
while True:
    os.system('clear')
    map.draw_room()
    map_action=input("What direction do you want to move [Up, Down, Left, Right]:   ").lower()
    map.move(map_action)
    time.sleep(1.5/ts)
    room_type=map.get_room_type()
    if map.check_movement(map_action) == True:
        if room_type=="random":
            room_type=random.choice(room_types)
            map.update_rooms()
        match room_type:
            case "empty":
                print("You are in an empty room.")
                time.sleep(1/ts)
            case "monster":
                enemy=enemy_character(name="Enemy", health=50, reward=10)
                print(f"You are in a room with a monster, the monster is a {enemy.name}.")
                time.sleep(1/ts)
                print(f"3 2 1 FIGHT!")
                time.sleep(2/ts)
                break
            case "treasure":
                treasure_item=random.choice(treasure)
                print(f"You are in a room with treasure, the treasure is a {treasure_item.name}.")
                time.sleep(0.5/ts)
                pick_action=input("Do you want to pick it up? [Y/N]:    ").lower()
                if pick_action=="y":
                    hero.pick(treasure_item)

This is a related snippet from main.py, and next is a snipped from map.py, which is being called using from assets.classes.map import map:
rooms=[
    ["empty","monster","random","random","random"],
    ["monster","random","random","random","random"],
    ["random","random","random","empty","random"],
    ["random","random","random","random","random"],
    ["empty","random","random","empty","boss"]
]

# Some other code containing ASCII art

class map:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.room=[0,0]
        self.rooms=rooms
    def draw_room(self):
        current_draw_room=paths_art.get(map_layout[self.room[0]][self.room[1]])
        print(current_draw_room)
    def get_room_type(self):
        return self.rooms[self.room[0]][self.room[1]]

# Some more code containing a move action

    def update_rooms(self):
        if self.rooms[self.room[0]][self.room[1]] != "empty":
            self.rooms[self.room[0]][self.room[1]] = "empty"

I was expecting it to ensure the room as empty whenever I retraced my steps in the maze, and just return "the room is empty". Using the built in debug tool, the map.rooms coordinate [1,0] for example stays as the predefined "monster" no matter what I have tried.

There's no need for the if check. There's no harm in setting the room to empty if it's already empty.

draw_room() needs to be called on an instance of the map class, not the class itself.

Also get_room_type() and update_rooms().

Sorry @Barmar, is it ok if you were to explain this a bit further? I will remove the if check, but I'm not sure what you mean by setting it as an instance of the map class instead of self, if it's ok maybe I could get an example.
Also what do you mean with "Also get_room_type() and update_rooms()?"

You need something like mymap = map() somewhere, then you should be using mymap.draw_room(), mymap.get_room_type(), etc. Read a tutorial on Python OOP somewhere.

Thanks but i do have such a defenition, it's just named map, that's why it's map.draw_room() etc, does the similar naming interfere with it?

map is the class name, not a variable containing an instance. Are you doing map = map()?

Yeah, that is exactly what i'm doing, i defined map()=map at the beginning after the class imports

Is that a problem?

Don't do that, it's extremely confusing. And also means you can't have multiple instances of the class. The standard naming convention is that class names have an initial capital letter, variables are lowercase.

So it should be class Map: and map = Map()

I don't see any code that modifies self.room. So how will you ever set anthing other than self.rooms[0][0] to empty? I suspect there's other code that changes the room, but without seeing how that works, I can't tell what's wrong. Please post a [mre].

If map.check_movement() updates self.room, the problem is that you're setting room_type before you call that.
